# best way to calculate statistics from a file in c#

Tags: c#

I have around 300k image files in a remote location. I download (have to) and write the details of these files to a text file (with some additional info). Due to the nature of the info I'm getting, I have to process each file as they arrive (Also I write each file info to a file line) to get some form of statistics for example, I have a list of objects with attributes size and count to see how many images of certain sizes I have.

I have also thought about getting everything read and written to a file without keeping any statistics info where I could just open the file again to add the statistics. But I can't think of a way to process a 250k line multi attribute file for statistics info.

I know the lists (yeah I have 2 of them) and the constant loop for each item is bugging the application down but is there another way? Right now it's been 2 hours and the application is still on 26k. For each image item, I do something like this to keep count where I check if an image comes with a certain size that did come before, I add it to that List item.

```
public void AddSizeTokens(Token token)
{
  int index = tokenList.FindIndex(item => item.size== token.size);
  if (index >= 0)
    tokenList[index].count+=1;
  else
    tokenList.Add(token);
}
```

What a single line from the file I write to looks like

```
Hits    Size     Downloads     Local Loc                   Virtual ID
204     88.3        4212        .../someImage.jpg       f-dd-edb2-4a64-b42
```

I'm downloading the files like below;

```
try
{
   using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
   {
     if (File.Exists(filePath + "/" + fileName + "." + ext))
     {
        return "File Exists: " + filePath + "/" + fileName + "." + ext;
     }
     client.DownloadFile(virtualPath, filePath + "/" + fileName + "." + ext);
     return "Downloaded: " + filePath + "/" + fileName + "." + ext;
   }
 }
 catch (Exception e)  {
      return"Problem Downloading " + fileName + ": " + e.Message;
 }
```

Comment: why do you have to download the file? do you need it's content? you can get it's size without downloading. Maybe creating a small sql database is an option?

Comment: Keep in mind since you're downloading the image files, your bottleneck can be your connection speed. You mention 26k files in ~2 hours, if we take an average file size of 200KB (not that much for an image imho) you've downloaded 5078,125MB at a rate of ~722KB/s. If this is a home connection, I think that's a rather respectable speed, especially if you're creating a separate connection for every image.

Comment: The images are around 150KB and I have to download them, that is for certain since size is not the only issue. I added the download method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I thought perhaps the coding was the issue. Some of the problem was indeed so. As per Daniel Hilgarth's instructions, changing to dictionary helped a lot, but only the first 30 minutes. Then It was getting worse by every minute.

The problem was apparently the innocent looking UI elements that I've fed information. They ate away so much cpu that it killed the application eventually. Minimizing UI info feed helped (1.5k per minute to at slowest 1.3k). Unbelievable! Hope it helps others who have similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

You should be changing your `tokenList` from `List<Token>` to `Dictionary<long, Token>`.
The key is the size.

Your code would look like this:

```
Dictionary<long, Token> tokens = new Dictionary<long, Token>();

public void AddSizeTokens(Token token)
{
    Token existingToken;
    if(!tokens.TryGetValue(token.size, out existingToken))
        tokens.Add(token.size, token);
    else
        existingToken.count += 1;
}
```

That will change it from an O(n) operation to a O(1) operation.

Another point to consider is Destrictor's comment. Your internet connection speed is very possibly the bottle neck here.

Comment: it looks prettier this way by it's memory usage so far. 2k files processed in 3 mins. Lets see what happens.

Comment: @mechanicum: The change proposed in my answer shouldn't have any impact on the memory consumption of your application.